# Eclipse not handling subpackages correctly

Tags: java, eclipse, package

I noticed what whenever I go to make a subpackage in another package, it will just rename the previous package unless there's already a .java file in it. How do I fix that?

Secondly, I just imported my repositories from BitBucket so that I can work on my plugins from my laptop. However, the import completely ignored all subpackaging, making a bunch of similarly-named packages. How do I fix that, too?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like an eclipse setup issue - you simply need to change the package display to Hierarchical, rather than flat.

In the package explorer, select the menu (the little triangle), then select `Package Presentation`, and then `Hierarchical`.

Hopefully this shows you what you're looking for.

Comment: I'm an idiot! Thanks for helping me sort out the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Click on the little downwards-pointing arrow to the right of Package Explorer. A menu should pop up. Go down to Package Presentation, and select "Hierarchical".

The reason this is the default view is because "subpackages" in Java don't really exist. That is:

```
java.util.concurrent
```

*isn't* a subpackage of

```
java.util
```

To Java, it's just a coincidence that the packages are named similarly.

Unfortunately, I can't seem to remember how I fixed the other issue... I'm decently sure I had fixed it earlier, but I can't seem to reproduce the steps for my current workspace. I'll update my answer if I can figure it out...